# Select a subset from list of permutations that satisfies a condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given set s of n elements, $S = {0, 1, 2, ... n}$ elements of which are all increasing, unique integers I want to obtain subset from set of its permutations but excluding "mirrored" ones (warning, this might be wrong wording, I will try to explain below).

E.g. Given three element set $S = {0, 1, 2}$

I can obtain set of all of the permutations i.e. $P = {
[0 1 2],                                                                                                                                                                                                            [0 2 1],                                                                                                                                                                                                            [1 0 2],                                                                                                                                                                                                            [1 2 0],                                                                                                                                                                                                            [2 0 1],                                                                                                                                                                                                            [2 1 0]}$

From which I am only interested in subset $P' = {[0 1 2],                                                                                                                                                                                              [0 2 1],                                                                                                                                                                                                            [1 0 2]}$

My question is how to obtain a general solution for finding such subset P' from set of permutations P of set S of size N.

That is how, given a list of permutations of integers i,j,k select from them permutations in a way in which i,j,k=k,j,i but i,j,k!=ikj.

I am sorry that I cant speak more coherently when phrasing my question, my lack of rigorous mathematical training is showing (as it is probably in the question itself already).

All help highly appreciated!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Usually a "cyclic" permutation means that the "circular order" is preserved.  So $(0,1,2), (1,2,0), (2,0,1)$ would all be excluded.  But $(2,1,0)$ would be fine, for example.  Not quite sure which permutations you are excluding.

Comment: edited my post to better try to describe my problem

Comment: Well, it's still not clear to me.  But maybe that does not matter...you have three permutations you like, for whatever reason.  So, assign numbers to them and then choose one of those three numbers at random.  If you want to generalize to larger alphabets, you'll really need to do a better job describing the permutations you like.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements of $S$ are increasing and unique (which I assume means distinct), then why wouldn't the answer be $\dfrac{1}{2}n!$?

Comment: This is probably correct, I was wondering if that is indeed the answer but was not sure.

Comment: How about if they were not increasing, yet distinct?

Comment: @KiwiMangoBanana It is not (necessarily) that the elements are increasing.  Rather it is that the indices associated with the elements are increasing.  Assuming that the set has $n$ elements, you can index the elements as $e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_n$.  Then, whatever analysis that applies to the example taken from the set whose elements are $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ will also apply to the set whose elements are $\{e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_n\}.$